# MySQL Auto-Increment query is returning two rows

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have an inno-db table with one primary key which is the auto-increment column. I am using the following query to find the next auto-increment id:

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='mytable';
```

However, when I view the results, I get two rows returned with two values (1352, 123841).  I've tried resetting the auto-increment value and even deleted the rows below 2000.  How can reset the table to return a single result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just might have two databases in the MySQL Instance with the same table name.

```
SELECT table_schema, Auto_increment
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='mytable';
```

If you are asking about the database you are standing in, run this

```
SELECT Auto_increment
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name='mytable'
AND table_schema=DATABASE();
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two tables in your db. Try to check the schema and you will find the reason:-

```
SELECT table_schema, Auto_increment
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='mytable';
```